# Mongodb sorting issue when using facet

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

mongodb sorting is not working when using facet and mongo aggregation. results are not sorting after the sort function used. i am converting the utc date fromat to date string.

also need to remove the _id for each document

please help me on the query

Input json payload which using

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "122434543sdf"
    },
    "eventName": "ev1",
    "channelId": "channel1",
    "domain": "domain1",
    "lob": "lob1",
    "eventCategory": "category1",
    "producerCSI": "1234",
    "topicName": "topic1",
    "dateTime": "2021-12-29T20:04:37Z",
    "errorDetailsList": [{
        "errorType": "Missing data",
        "count": {
            "$numberLong": "1"
        }
    }, {
        "errorType": "Invalid Data",
        "count": {
            "$numberLong": "1"
        }
    }]
}
]
}
```

Mongo query i have written

```
 db.failureevents.aggregate( [
{$unwind: { "path": "$errorDetailsList", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true} },
{$addFields: {errorType: {$arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray: "$errorDetailsList"}, 0]}}},
{$addFields: {"errorType": "$errorType.v"}},
{$lookup : { "from": "errordescription", "localField": "errorType", "foreignField": "errorType", "as": "dataset" }},
{$unwind: { "path": "$dataset", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
 {$facet: {
    "top": [
 { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "lob": "$lob",
            "channel": "$channelId",
            "domain": "$domain",
            "eventCategory": "$eventCategory",
            "prodcuerCSI": "$producerCSI",
            "topicName": "$topicName",
            "eventName": "$eventName",
            "errorType":"$dataset.errorType",
            "errorMessage":"$dataset.errorMessage",
            "dateTime":"$dateTime",
            "date" : { "$dateFromString" : { "dateString" : "$dateTime"} },
        },
        "errorCount": {"$sum" : "$errorDetailsList.count"},
    }
}],
 "rest": [ {$count: 'count'}]
}},
    { "$project": { "_id" : 0,"data": { "$concatArrays": ["$top", "$rest"] }}},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }},
  {$sort: {"date" : -1}},
   { $skip: 0 },
 { $limit: 100},
 ]);
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what the desired output would look like?   
Perhaps also a little explain of what you are trying to do in addition to attesting what isn't working.  I also do not understand why `eventName` is part of the `$group`.   Wouldn't event name be unique in this data design?   And why the lookup into error description early on instead of collecting the counts and THEN doing lookup to get the description?

Comment: At the point you are sorting the documents do not have a top-level field named "date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `$group` stage in MongoDB aggregation retains only those fields in the the group specification.

In your example pipeline the `$group` stage in the `top` section will return documents that have only 2 top-level fields, `_id` and `errorCount`.

At the point `{$sort: {"date" : -1}}` is executed, there is no `date` field at the top level, so the sort has not effect.

Solution: either use `{$sort: {"_id.date" : -1}}` or use a projection that moves the fields embedded in `_id` to the top level before sorting.